# UIViewRoot is null using JSF plus the PortletFaces bridge on Liferay

Tags: jsf, liferay, portlet

How could UIViewRoot be left null?  Is that not the root component of the component tree?  I have a relatively simple JSF webapp at this point and no clue why it is failing.

In particular, I have one `h:panelGroup`:

```
    <h:panelGroup id="xmlValidationResults" layout="block"
      styleClass="tp-form-action-results"
      rendered="#{configuration.xmlValidationResult != null}">
```

That works fine, but if I add additional rendering criteria:

```
    <h:panelGroup id="xmlValidationResults" layout="block"
      styleClass="tp-form-action-results"
      rendered="#{configuration.xmlValidationResult != null && configuration.xmlValidationResult.warningOrWorse}">
```

I end up getting these error messages in my log:

```
20:43:07,796 ERROR LiferayLocalePhaseListener:61 - viewRoot is null!
20:43:07,797 ERROR [render_portlet_jsp:154] java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.portletfaces.bridge.BridgeImpl.indicateNamespacingToConsumers(BridgeImpl.java:594)
    at org.portletfaces.bridge.BridgeImpl.doFacesRequest(BridgeImpl.java:426)
    at org.portletfaces.bridge.GenericFacesPortlet.doEdit(GenericFacesPortlet.java:138)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:330)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:93)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:639)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:726)
```

For completeness, here is my template.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
  <h:head />
  <h:body>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="liferay-tableau-portlet.css"
      target="head" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="liferay-tableau-portlet.js" target="head" />
    <h:panelGroup styleClass="tp-container" layout="block">
      <h:panelGroup styleClass="tp-header" layout="block">
        <ui:insert name="header"></ui:insert>
      </h:panelGroup>
      <h:panelGroup styleClass="tp-content" layout="block">
        <ui:insert name="content">Whoops, you should not be seeing this...</ui:insert>
      </h:panelGroup>
      <h:panelGroup styleClass="tp-footer" layout="block">
        <ui:insert name="footer"></ui:insert>
        <h:messages id="liferayTableauPortletMessages" globalOnly="true"
          showDetails="true" />
      </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGroup>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

And here is my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<body>
  <ui:composition template="template.xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <ui:define name="header">
      <h:panelGroup styleClass="tp-application-info">
        <span>#{configuration.applicationName}
          #{configuration.applicationVersion}
          (#{configuration.applicationBuildTimestamp})</span>
      </h:panelGroup>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
      <h:form id="form">
        <h:panelGroup id="formFields" styleClass="tp-form-fields">
          <fieldset class="tp-form-fieldset">
            <div>
              <h:outputLabel id="xmlLabel" for="xml" styleClass="tp-label">XML Configuration:</h:outputLabel>
            </div>
            <h:inputTextarea id="xml" value="#{configuration.xml}"
              validator="#{configuration.validateXml}" cols="80" rows=10 />
          </fieldset>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup id="xmlValidationResults" layout="block"
          styleClass="tp-form-action-results"
          rendered="#{configuration.xmlValidationResult != null}">
          <span>can you see me?</span>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup id="formActions" styleClass="tp-form-actions">
          <h:commandLink id="createWebContentAction" styleClass="tp-action"
            action="#{configuration.createWebContent}">
            <span>Create Web Content</span>
          </h:commandLink>
          <h:commandLink id="extractTableauThumbnailsAction"
            styleClass="tp-action"
            action="#{configuration.extractTableauThumbnails}">
            <span>Extract Tableau Thumbnails</span>
          </h:commandLink>
        </h:panelGroup>
      </h:form>
    </ui:define>
  </ui:composition>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `<f:view/>` tag around `<h:head/>` and `<h:body>`.